# Why this sql request don't work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the countries list where produce pieces for the first time in 2008.
this is my sql req :

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM pays p
WHERE p.id_pays != (
    SELECT DISTINCT pays.id_pays
    FROM pays
    JOIN emission ON emission.id_pays = pays.id_pays
    WHERE MIN(YEAR(emission.dateFrappe_emission)) != 2008
)
```

It returned me :

> " #1111 - Invalid use of group function";

But this res works :

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM pays p
WHERE p.id_pays != (
    SELECT DISTINCT pays.id_pays
    FROM pays
    JOIN emission ON emission.id_pays = pays.id_pays
    WHERE YEAR(emission.dateFrappe_emission) = 2008
)
```

Can you please help me ?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM pays p
WHERE p.id_pays NOT IN (
    SELECT pays.id_pays
    FROM pays
    JOIN emission 
      ON emission.id_pays = pays.id_pays
    GROUP BY pays.id_pays
    HAVING MIN(YEAR(emission.dateFrappe_emission)) != 2008
)` You should use aggregate function in `SELECT/HAVING clause`

Comment: Thx but : #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Try with `NOT IN` instead of `!=`

Comment: Thanks, working, i let you put this as an answer and i will validate :P

Comment: Don't over-use DISTINCT. It is rarely needed. `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM pays` - so you have completely duplicate rows you want to get rid of? Rows you cannot even distinguish, because all fields are exactly the same? This is not likely. Having to use DISTINCT at all is often a sign for poorly written queries. Just an advice you might want to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions with `SELECT` and `HAVING` clause, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM pays p 
WHERE p.id_pays NOT IN (SELECT pays.id_pays 
                        FROM pays 
                        JOIN emission 
                          ON emission.id_pays = pays.id_pays 
                        GROUP BY pays.id_pays 
                        HAVING MIN(YEAR(emission.dateFrappe_emission)) != 2008 )
```

Comment: 8 minute before validate. Thx a lot :D

Comment: @Antoine One more thing, is column `pays.id_pays` NOT NULL?

Comment: @Antoine `NOT IN` with `SELECT` will be `NULL` if one of result is `NULL`. You need to add then `WHERE p.id_pays NOT IN (SELECT COALESCE(pays.id_pays,-1) ...` but it is not your case. Check **[demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398562)**

Answer (score 2):

First production in 2008? Isn't this simply:

```
select *
from pays
where
(
  select min(year(emission.datefrappe_emission))
  from emission 
  where emission.id_pays = pays.id_pays
) = 2008;
```